# Fullscreen Post-Processing Blooming on iOS Device with Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, shader, fragment-shader

I am just about to finish a new game and I am currently playing with fragment shaders which I apply on a fullscreen SKEffectNode to do some post-processing. The effect I am after is a slight bloom/glow effect which makes the whole game more crispy for the eyes. Problem is that using even the simplest bloom/blur effect on a fullscreen node in Sprite Kit makes the Framerate drop to almost zero.

So what is the best way to do post-processing for a fullscreen scene in Sprite Kit?

EDIT:

Here is the Shader-Code that I am using:

```
precision lowp float;

void main() {

vec4 sum = vec4(0.0);
int j;
int i;

for( i= -2 ;i < 2; i++) {
    for (j = -2; j < 2; j++) {
        sum += texture2D(u_texture, v_tex_coord + vec2(j, i)*0.004) * 0.25;
    }
}

if (texture2D(u_texture, v_tex_coord).r < 0.3) {
    gl_FragColor = sum*sum*0.012 + texture2D(u_texture, v_tex_coord);
}
else {
    if (texture2D(u_texture, v_tex_coord).r < 0.5) {
        gl_FragColor = sum*sum*0.009 + texture2D(u_texture, v_tex_coord);
    }
    else {
        gl_FragColor = sum*sum*0.0075 + texture2D(u_texture, v_tex_coord);
    }
}
}
```

I was searching the internet for OpenGL ES Bloom Shader and found the code above which I ported to work with SpriteKit SKShader-Nodes.

Problem is that this Shader drops Framerate on my first-get iPad Mini (which I am using for dev) to 10 fps. I really love the effect it makes - or a bloom effect in general - and using a shader is far more easier than implementing this effect by stacking and blending different sprites.

Does anyone know an OpenGL ES optimized bloom or motion blur shader? Again, I am applying this on my
SKScene.shader property.

Comment: There is no 'best way' to do almost anything. I suggest you post the shader code you are using to allow us to point out any inefficiencies. Plus you really really need to tell us what device you are using (hopefully not the simulator).

Comment: I've edited my question and added the shader-code as well as more detail to my problem!

Comment: Just a quick thought... What if I replace the for-loops with static lines of code?

Comment: With all due respect @LearnCocos2D there is almost never not a best way to do nearly everything.